# Making local modifications to npm dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a nodejs project where I include a library (`hubot-xmpp`) as a dependency in my package.json file. However, that library has an issue that I have a solution to, but that change is not going to make its way back upstream because it's a hack for a very specific situation. To further complicate things, `hubot-xmpp` depends on the library `node-xmpp`, which I also have to patch to hack around an issue with Openfire and a TLS handshake issue.

Because those libraries are installed automatically by npm, my changes won't be included if I, for example, deploy to heroku or (I assume) run `npm update`.

I'm not very experienced with nodejs and how situations like these are usually handled. To summarize:

- My application pulls in hubot-xmpp as a dependency
- I need to patch hubot-xmpp
- hubot-xmpp has a dependency on node-xmpp
- I need to patch node-xmpp

How do I solve this in a sane way? Do I fork both projects, apply my patches, change my dependency on hubot-xmpp to point to my fork, then update the dependency in my fork of hubot-xmpp to point to my fork of node-xmpp? That seems like a kind of sane way, I suppose, but I don't know enough to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Why not fork the library and depend on the fork? That way you could in theory merge in future updates to the library. You wouldn't necessarily have to publish the fork in npm either, just point package.json at the repo.